# Left join returning duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, left-join, join

**Issue is being resolved with the help of comments**

Following is mysql query in which i have been trying to join table `notes` with two other tables `user_facility` and `users` but when i run the query then it returns duplicate rows. I used the same way of joining with one of my similar queries and in that by using `Distinct` my issue got resolved but using that trick with the following is not doing the trick. Kindly let me know how can i resolve the issue so distinct rows being returned.

Thanks,

```
SELECT DISTINCT a,b,c
            FROM notes
            LEFT JOIN user_facility ON notes.fk_resident_id = user_facility.fk_user_id
            LEFT JOIN users ON notes.fk_resident_id = users.id where user_facility.fk_facility_id = 101
```

Comment: Try dropping one or both LEFT from the JOINs

Comment: Are you saying that you are getting duplicated rows in your result even with the DISTINCT?

Comment: Using `distinct`won't get you duplicate rows. The rows differ in maybve just on column. What are you trying to achive?

Comment: @juergend that my query returns me distinct rows and duplication should not occur...

Comment: There must be something about the resultant rows that makes them distinct. Embedded spaces? O and 0 swaps?

Comment: if you don't get distinct rows then some data must be skipped.

Comment: @ethrbunny my issue gets resolved thanks i took a look in the resultant rows and you are right they are distinct on certain fields.